# excel how to calculate percentage with different bandwidth (not starting at 0)

Tags: excel, calculator, percentage

[image]

Hi, I'm trying to get the percentage (column E) of the percentage of the realization and target (B/A) but within the bandwidth of C and D, which are 75% and 125% of column A. And from there I want it to use that as the bandwidth between 0 and 200%, so if B3 = 26,30, E3 should be 200%, and if B3 = 15,78 E3 should be 0% etc.

The bandwidth (C2 and D2) are variables, so they can be changed, but the bandwidth of score will be always be between 0 and 200%.

The 10% and 101% are just typed in there, so nevermind that. There is where the score should be between 0 and 200%. The values in B wont be below the value in C or higher then the values in D, so no worries about that.

Hope someone can get his head around this, I dont know how to calculate percentages with a different bandwidth. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not clear to me what the actual results are supposed to be. Can you explain how you calculate the desired result manually? It would also be helpful to have an example that doesn't include stuff we need to ignore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree it's not the easiest question to understand but I see what result you're trying to arrive at. Essentially if you're at the lower bound (whatever % you decide to attribute to it), you're at 0% to target and if you're at the higher bound (again whatever % you decide to attribute to it) you're at 200% to target. Plug the following formula into cell E3 and fill down:

=2*(B3-C3)/(D3-C3)

And format as a %.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: P.S. When you test the answer you may get answers such as 99.90% or 201% etc. This will happen if the results in Columns C and D are the result of a calculation where the actual answer is more than 2 decimal places but is only displayed in 2 decimal places (e.g. I am guessing in Cell C4 you have the following formula: =$A4*$C$2) where the actual answer is 15.375 but is displayed as 15.38. To counter this I would wrap any calculations in =Round(cell ref, 2). This way, the ACTUAL answer will both BE 15.38 AND be displayed as 15.38. Hope that makes sense. Thanks :)

Comment: This is exactly how I meant it! And it works perfectly! Thanks!